# Probability of $X^2$ (random variable) using pchisq() function in r

Tags: r, random-variable

How to find the probability of a random variable $X^2$ using `pchisq()` function in r?

$p\,(1<X^2<2)$

How to find the probability of this random variable using `pchisq()` function in r.

Comment: Did you try pchisq(2) - pchisq(1)? (assuming that $X^2$ has a $\chi^2$ distribution)

Comment: Questions about code are off-topic on CV. However, the relationship between the square of a random variable $X \sim (0,1)$ and $\chi^2_{1\,df}$, as well as the concept of probability as the area under the pdf curve, may be more appropriate for the site, and I tried to give your question this angle on my answer.

Comment: Well your question explicitly asked how to do it in R, so you are saying that your own question is off topic?

Comment: @fcop  Is your comment addressed to me? If so, I agree that the question as is  does not belong in CV. I was hoping the OP would be reframed,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not clear as to whether the random variable $X$ is distributed as a standard normal distribution, $X \sim N(0,1)$ as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_related_to_chi-squared_distribution#Derivations_of_the_pdf). If this is the case, then $X^2 \sim \chi^2_{1\,\text{df}}$.

It follows that what you need is the area under the curve of the pdf of the chi square distribution with $1$ degree of freedom between $1$ and $2$:

$P(1\,<\,X2\,<\,2)\,=\,P(1 \,< \,\chi^2_1\,<\,2)\,= \,P(\chi^2_1\,>\,2)\,-\,P(\chi^2_1\,>\,1)$. Graphically it corresponds to the green area under the curve below:

[image]

The actual value can be found on tables, or with the R code already provided in the prior answer: `pchisq(2, 1) - pchisq(1, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that $X \sim N(0,1)$, it is well known that this means that $X^2$ has a Chi-square distribution $X^2 \sim \chi^2(k=1)$.

```
pchisq(2,df=1) - pchisq(1,df=1)
```

Comment: tats d solution given. Can u pl explain that it detail @ACE